Is there a way to save a json file from an API request to a Table in Snowflake using an UDF?
I'm trying to save a JSON file that I get from an API request as a Snowflake Table
I've created a UDF and I'm able to get the response data from the API, I've tried saving this data using session.write_pandas but I'm getting an error pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ('cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values', 'Conversion failed for column fimFranchisee with type object')
Here's my sample code:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fetch_api_data()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
PACKAGES = ('requests', 'pandas', 'snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'getData'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (access_integration)
SECRETS = ('api_key' = api_key)
AS
$$
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
def getData (session: snowpark.Session):    
    apiurl = 'https://exmaple.com'
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',        
        'Authorization': 'Bearer bearer_token'
    }
    response = rq.post(apiurl, headers = header)
    data = response.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    session.write_pandas(df, table_name= 'RAW_SEGMENT', database='DEV_1_RAW', schema='SCHEMA!', auto_create_table=True, overwrite=True)
    return data
$$;

CALL fetch_api_data();

As stated, I'm able to see the data using return data, but I haven't found a way to save this data into a table. I get the error mentioned above when trying to save it using session.write_pandas.
Is there any way to save this unstructured data in a table? It's enough for me if the data gets all saved as an object data type.

The error occured as it seems there is a combination of list and non-list values in fimFranchisee column which is causing the problem.
It would be  helpful if you could have shared a sample data with us.
If you just want to save it in a table, you could use a VARIANT column in Snowflake  to store unstructured data like JSON.
df = pd.DataFrame({'RAW_JSON': [data]})

Another option is to normalise the data process each column.
